# Rewriting approximated terms

Tags: logarithms, linear-approximation

The following data are inferred from a presentation slide, so I do not much info.

Using linear approximation and log rules $\sqrt x $ can be rewritten as $\frac{x+1}{2}$, where $(1 \leq x \lt 2) $ ... (1)

I understood the Eq. (1).

Now the slide says, in the range $(2 \leq x \lt 4)$,

$ \sqrt x = 2^{\frac{log_2(x)}{2}} \approx 2^{\frac{(1+x-1)}{2}}$   ... (2)

Could some one tell me, how and why do we get the term `$x$' approximated to $ (1+x-1) $ in Eq. (2) ?

Note! I am aware that using linear approximation  $log_2(x) \approx x-1 $

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is a typo in 
$ \sqrt x \approx 2^{\frac{(1+x-1)}{2}}$

because it is not a correct approximate in the range $2 \leq x < 4$

Case of $x=2 $ then $ \sqrt 2 \approx 2^{\frac{(1+2-1)}{2}}=2$ is false.

Case of $x=4 $ then $ \sqrt 4 \approx 2^{\frac{(1+4-1)}{2}}=4$ is false.

If we use the Taylor's series :
$$f(x)=f(x_1)+f'(x_1)(x-x_1)+...$$
with $x_1=2$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ hense $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$
we obtain :

$$f(x)\approx \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(x-2)$$

Case of $x=2 $ then $ \sqrt 2 \approx \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(2-2)=\sqrt{2}$ is OK.

Case of $x=4 $ then $ \sqrt 4 \approx \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(4-2)=\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2} \simeq 2.12$ is OK.

Another kind of approximate on the form $\sqrt{x} \approx 2^{ax+b}$ is identifed so that $2^{2a+b}=\sqrt{2}$ and $ 2^{4a+b}=2$ leading to $a=\frac{1}{4}$ and $b=0$ :
$$\sqrt{x}\approx 2^{x/4}$$
on the range$2 \leq x < 4$

but the preceeding approximate $f(x)\approx \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(x-2)$ is better.

Of course, even better approximates can be obtained in considering more terms of the Taylor's series.

Comment: what is the name of the approximation which is of the form $ \sqrt x \approx 2^{ax+b}$ ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no particular name for each form of function used to approximate a given function. On a more general viewpoint, this is relevant to the general term of "regression" or fitting, when the parameters of an approximate function are optimized in order to fit at the best a set of points of a given function.